# How can I copy only the data from one database to another one which is on other server in the same network?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have 2 Databases on 2 SQL Server. I will copy the data from the 1st one to the 2nd, which is empty.

The 2 Databases are exactly the same but on 2 Servers.

The new one is on a Server where I have no SA User. I have only DB Owner user.

Can I get only the data from the 1st one and insert itin the 2nd without problems :D ?

What T-SQL Code can I use to do this?

Comment: use the wizard. is this a one time only task? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard for this task.

Right click the empty database in SSMS -> Tasks -> Import data and then follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If it's something you do often, then one option is to add a linked server. Info here: [Create Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

your query will be something like:

```
insert into dbo.table_name(col1,col2,col3)
SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM [YOURSERVER].database.dbo.table_name
```